# Problem in getting 100 th power of any particluar value

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Suppose i need 100 power of say 1.5 then how can i get that .

Any formula how to get this in iphone .For example i need the value of 1.5^100 , then how can i get that in objective c.

Comment: I just have to ask: what kind of app are you building? Does it involve astrophysics? Cryptography? Investment plans for immortals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `pow()` function from math.h:

```
NSLog(@"%.f", pow(1.5,100) );
```

If you need any other math related operations, I would check out:

[Objective-C Math functions](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/objective-c-math-functions/)

Comment: can u just tell me how to use as i dont know that for the above example

Comment: @ Justin the value of that function is very big and that cannot be accomodated in float so whats other datatype ,means which should i use

Comment: @abhi.shah88 - What about a double?

Comment: i used long long value but it gave negative value can u replicate that at your end as well or wat

Comment: If you really need to do arithmetic beyond the precision of a double, you'll need to either hand-roll it or use a library; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries .